# calling c function in bison

Tags: c, bison

I am trying a function that is in a C file from .y file

The lex file looks like this

```
%{


#include "Expression.h"
#include "Parser.h"

#include <stdio.h>

%}

%option outfile="Lexer.c" header-file="Lexer.h"
%option warn nodefault

%option reentrant noyywrap never-interactive nounistd
%option bison-bridge

LPAREN      "("
RPAREN      ")"
PLUS        "+"
MULTIPLY    "*"


ALPHABET    [a-z]+
NUMBER      [0-9]+
WS          [ \r\n\t]*

%%
 /* Rules */
{WS}            { /* Skip blanks. */ }
{NUMBER}        { sscanf_s(yytext, "%d", &yylval->value); return TOKEN_NUMBER; }
{ALPHABET}      { sscanf_s(yytext, "%c", &yylval->value);printf("%s",yytext); return TOKEN_ALPHABET;}
{MULTIPLY}      { return TOKEN_MULTIPLY; }
{PLUS}          { return TOKEN_PLUS; }
{LPAREN}        { return TOKEN_LPAREN; }
{RPAREN}        { return TOKEN_RPAREN; }
.               {  }

%%

int yyerror(const char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error:%s\n",msg);
    return 0;
}
```

The yacc file is

```
%{

/*
 * Parser.y file
 * To generate the parser run: "bison Parser.y"
 */

#include "Expression.h"
#include "Parser.h"
#include "Lexer.h"

int yyerror(SExpression **expression, yyscan_t scanner, const char *msg);

%}

%code requires {

#ifndef YY_TYPEDEF_YY_SCANNER_T
#define YY_TYPEDEF_YY_SCANNER_T
typedef void* yyscan_t;
#endif

}

%output  "Parser.c"
%defines "Parser.h"

%define api.pure
%lex-param   { yyscan_t scanner }
%parse-param { SExpression **expression }
%parse-param { yyscan_t scanner }
%parse-param { char **str}
%union {

    int value;
    SExpression *expression;
}

%left '+' TOKEN_PLUS
%left '*' TOKEN_MULTIPLY

%token <value> TOKEN_ALPHABET
%token TOKEN_LPAREN
%token TOKEN_RPAREN
%token TOKEN_PLUS
%token TOKEN_MULTIPLY
%token <value> TOKEN_NUMBER

%type <expression> expr
%type <expression> l
%%
letters: l {}
    l: TOKEN_ALPHABET {printf("alphabet",$1); $$ = createAlphabet( $1);}
    ;

input
    : letters { printf("alphabet"); }
    ;

expr
    : expr TOKEN_PLUS expr { $$ = createOperation( ePLUS, $1, $3 ); }
    | expr TOKEN_MULTIPLY expr { $$ = createOperation( eMULTIPLY, $1, $3 ); }
    | TOKEN_LPAREN expr TOKEN_RPAREN { $$ = $2; }
    | TOKEN_NUMBER { $$ = createNumber($1); }
    ;


%%
```

The function that I am trying to call is declared in expression.h and included in yacc file.
The function is

```
char **createAlphabet(char str[])
{
    char b[100];
    b[0] = str[0];

    if (b == NULL)
        return NULL;

    //b->left = left;

    return &b;

}
```

But when I put a breakpoint inside this function, the formal argument won't have the correct value. It says error reading characters of string.

Can anybody tell me what could be going wrong? I am pretty sure there are quite a few mistakes and I guess it is kind of vague but I wanted to know the correct method to call the function in a c file from .y file

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is that you have to call it with the correct parameter type. I'm certain that you're ignoring a compiler warning about that.

You've declared `TOKEN_ALPHABET` to have type tag `value` which is of type `int`, and your scanner code attempts to fill in the `value` member of the `yylval` union with a single character. (Although you do that in almost the most complicated way imaginable. `yylval->value = yytext[0]` would work just fine, and the way you do it is not correct since `sscanf` expects a `char*` rather than an `int*`. Your compiler should have warned you about that, too.)

However, in your bison action you then call `createAlphabet($1)`, where `$1` is a `TOKEN_ALPHABET` token (and consequently an `int`), but `createAlphabet` is declared to receive a `char[]` argument. In C, arrays used as formal parameters decay to pointers, so you are effectively declaring `createAlphabet` to take a pointer to a character string (`char*`) and giving it an integer. Treating a small integer as a pointer is officially undefined behaviour, but I can tell you how things will behave: your program will die with a segfault. (Usual UB disclaimers apply.)

Even if that didn't happen, you immediately return the address of a local variable, which is a dangling pointer; any attempt to use the return value of `createAlphabet` is also undefined behaviour, but its consequences are much less predicatble, and consequently more dangerous.

It's impossible for `b` to be `NULL`, by the way. If your compiler didn't warn you about that, it's because you're not compiling with the correct compiler flags; you should always enable all warnings, and heed them.

Other than all that, there is nothing wrong with how you are trying to call C functions from your bison-generated parser. The problems are really almost all about the C programming.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I'm new to lex and yacc. I didn't know that <value> corresponds to int. Could you please how I can accept a sequence of characters ? My input is an array of characters. So what should my TOKEN_ALPHABET be ?

Comment: I don't want the code. A verbal explanation will do

Comment: Your `%union` declaration defines `int value;`, so it's surprising that you say "I didn't know that `<value>` corresponds to int". Furthermore, your scanner pattern -- `{ALPHABET}` -- matches a single character, and your use of `scanf("%c",...` makes it clear that you expect only one character. Where did all that code come from? It's not hard to recognize word tokens in flex/bison -- there are tons of simple examples on the web -- but the code you present is doing something else. In short, I don't really know where to start. You can't use flex/bison without a basic understanding of C.

Comment: The code is not mine. Its one of the examples I found on internet. I thought <value> is some sort of keyboard and didn't realize that its coming from the union. I'm trying to understand the entire flow by adding few stuff of my own.

Comment: @Aadithya: There's an example of a bison-bridge lexer which matches IDs as strings in the flex manual, http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Bison-Bridge.html#Bison-Bridge

Comment: @Aadithya: The code you are using as a guide is really not very helpful. (It's hard to say which part is yours, so I take back my earlier slam at the code itself. But still...) You'd be better off with the flex and bison manuals, or -- even better -- John Levine's excellent book (which you might be able to find a way of reading online).

Comment: My code is only the ALPHABET part and the createAlphabet(). Thanks a lot for the assist .

Comment: Hey! If you could throw some light on this as well, I would be really. I found this example online for recognizing verbs. I don't want the paste the entire program here because it would appear as a paragraph I guess.

What it does is it recognizes the whole word together.

%%
is |
am |
be   {printf(".....");}

%%

But when I do this is my lex file, Visual studio starts giving errors saying  'is' is undefined, 'am' is undefined etc., 

Am I missing something ? I even tried putting them inside quotes :/

Answer (score 0):

using %c with sscanf, it will expect a char argument, not an int.  so i expect it to write one character to the first byte and the other 3 bytes will be uninitialized.

Why not add a char buffer to your %union and use %s with sscanf instead?

It's also a little odd that you're declaring the argument for createAlphabet as char[] instead of char.

Comment: I want to pass a sequence of characters. So shouldn't that be char[] ?

Comment: no.  you need to provide storage for the characters somewhere else and pass a pointer to them to this function.  alternatively you could use std::string